# How to center more divs inside a big div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know there's a lot of tutorial that helps you to center a div inside another div... but my problem is bigger and so far I didn't find any useful solution.

I'd like to make something like that:
[image]

Where everything should be horizontally center aligned.

And the purple div have some external contents, so it's height isn't fixed, and I need it to stay inside the red div (obviously it can scroll if the the contents are too much, but the scroll should be for the grey div, not like in the red frame).

I tried to play with positioning, but with absolute and relative stuff it's working until I try to put the child of the child.

Anyone can help me?

If you're not in the mood to write code for me you can even link me an useful tutorial, because I've found a lot of help for parent-child positioning, but nothing for parent-child-grandchild situation...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1427878)

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-positioning-and-flexbox-explained/ you can check this url. Please try to use flexbox.

Comment: Use 'flex' . Make every container display flex.

Comment: This is my code so far: https://codepen.io/arberto99/pen/mdWpXwb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's true or not but you can still refer to it if you want :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
* {
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#container {
width: 98%;
margin-left:1%;
margin-top:1%;
border: 5px solid grey;
}
#main {
border: 5px solid red;
width:580px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:50px;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
#logo {
border: 5px solid green;
width:400px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:20px;
}
#grid {
border: 5px solid blue;
width:540px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:20px;
}
#content {
border: 5px solid purple;
width:400px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="main">
<div id="logo">Logo</div>
<div id="grid">Grid</div>
<div id="content">
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
<h3>HELLO</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are looking for something like this?

https://codepen.io/akshaybhat301094/pen/MWprQvO

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.logo {
  width: 60%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

.grid {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.expandable {
  width: 60%;
  max-height: 120px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div class="expandable"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but as soon as I add some long content to the expandable div, the contents freak out like this: https://codepen.io/arberto99/pen/GRWyQLq

Comment: Yes to fix that you can add some max-height and overflow as a scroll. So that you can see a scrollbar for the same